# Вызов хранимой процедуры в Java

Tags: java

Есть процедура в БД Oracle:

```
PROCEDURE report_uslugi(p_dat1 in DATE ,p_dat2 in DATE ,rc1 IN OUT pkg_global.ref_cursor_type) AS
p_dat_from DATE;
p_dat_to DATE;

BEGIN

p_dat_from := p_dat1;
p_dat_to := p_dat2;

OPEN rc1 FOR SELECT *** FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT *** FROM *** WHERE ***) ***);

END report_uslugi;
```

Я ее сильно сократил, заменив столбцы, таблицы, условия на ***, но дело не в этом. Процедура рабочая и при ее вызове выгружается список услуг

Как вызвать такую процедуру в Java? Я так пытаюсь сделать

```
try (Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection()) {
    CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call pkg_report_usl.report_uslugi(?, ?, ?)}");
    cstmt.setDate(1, sqlDate1);
    cstmt.setDate(2, sqlDate2);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.REF_CURSOR);
    cstmt.execute();

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Получаю ошибку

> java.sql.SQLException: Недопустимый тип столбца: 2012 at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:4369)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:137)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:335)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:583)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1603)
>   at myapp.start.Main.start(Main.java:63) at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
>   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
>   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
>   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method) at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
>   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
>   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method) at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

В строке `cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.REF_CURSOR);`

Как правильно ее вызвать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle он и в Африке Oracle -  у них все по своему через одно место :)

Попробуйте так:

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Только надо использовать родной JDBC драйвер Oracle

Comment: Спасибо, вчера еще разобрался, забыл отписать сюда. Если уж вы ответили можно еще такой вопрос. При вызове процедуры есть параметры типа даты, я делаю так call.setDate(1, Дата); Вот где Дата не знаю как правильно прописать формат даты. В БД даты хранятся в виде 01.12.2018, а я получается указываю в SQL формате дату в виде 2018-12-01 Как вообще даты задать правильно? Можно даже ссылку на пример. Спасибо.